# Redis stream command passing message with parsed value

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I am creating the client using Redis and node js, I want to add a message to stream with the below format. I am facing an issue when trying the parse the message with the request body value.

```
async function userRegister (request) {
  var userID = request.body.userID
  var username = request.body.userName

  redisClient.xadd(
    'user:create',
    '*',
    'module',
    `userRegister`,
    'request_id',
    '2312432434',
    'message',
    `{"module":"*","user_id":"1","username":"fffff"}`, // this works bcoz its string.

    `{"module":"*","userID":"1","username":"here i need pass the above request body value"}`,

    function (err, resp) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      } else {
        console.log(resp)
      }
    }
  )

}
```

Comment: And your problem is?! A wild guess: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: `\`{"module":"*","userID":"1","username":"${request.body.userName}"}\`` ? something like this?

Comment: yes, this wat i required, thank you